# can I tap into or expose a javascript closure context?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, closures, angular-decorator

Suppose I have something like (modeled after angularJS services):

```
function createFuncWithClosure() {
  var c=3;
  var op=function(a,b){return a+b+c};
  return {fn:function(d,e){return op(2*d,e*d)}};
}

var obj=createFuncWithClosure();
```

now `obj.fn(1,2)` will return `9`  (2*1+2*2+3).

Given that you have both `createFuncWithClosure` and `obj` is there a way to:

1. Get or modify the value of `op`
2. Get or modify the value of `c`
3. List `c` and `op` as being part of the closure environment
   of `obj.fn`?    (google chrome's debugger can display those...)
4. What changes that would allow such tapping into the closures
   possible?      (public getter/setter / making them all children of a
   single object and setting a getter/setter to it?)

maybe I am missing some `Function.__closures__` somewhere....

Clarification: This Q is simplified down and based on an attempt to implement some changes to an angularJS service using $provide.decorator and reaching what seems to be some of the limitations of this tool resulting in an attempt to try to understand how an angular service should be written to allow any of it's aspects to be easily decorated. so answers relating to angular would also be very welcome.

Comment: In general, if you want to allow access to things like this, you use an object rather than a closure, and make these properties of the object.

Comment: They would need to be exposed in the return object, or if the public function used the variables in question you could potentially `.toString()` it and rebuild the function with some tweaks, but any references to local vars in it's original scope would be lost. Best bet is probably to change the third party code and submit a pull-request if open source